# How to get mobile sreen size with Xamarin C#?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make my application responsive, so I need the size of the screen, but I can't find any code. Does anyone know the code for the size of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `Xamarin.Android`:

```
var x = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
var y = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
```

Xamarin also has an Android sample app: [Detect Screen Size](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/)

For `Xamarin.iOS`:

```
var x = UIScreen.MainScreen.CurrentMode.Size.Width;
var y = UIScreen.MainScreen.CurrentMode.Size.Height;
```

Comment: var x = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
            var y = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;

            TextView width = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.screenWidthDp);

            sendMail.Click += delegate 
            {
               width.Text = Convert.ToString(x);
            };

Comment: I get no result in my TextView.

Comment: @Test And you have clicked on your sendMail Button? If you set a breakpoint on the `width.Text = ... ` what value is your `x` variable?

Comment: The value is: 320.

Comment: Indeed but it's still weird that my textview is empty.

Comment: So now I can use this in a if statement and then I can use the setContentView for small, large etc. layout?

Comment: @Test Yes you can, you also might want to read the following as the Android OS can auto choose the best matching layout if you follow their naming requirements : https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I will look at it. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Test No problem, happy Xammie Coding... ;-)